# Eclipse unable to find raw()method while using Cucumber datatable

Tags: datatable, cucumber

In my feature file i am using datatable
Feature File
    And verify for incorrect or incomplete Address
            |/api/          |
            |/api/2020-05-30|
            |/api/20200404  |
            |/api/abcfghj   |
I am using eclipse and In step definition file, when I am trying to add raw() method for datatable its unable to populate the method. While mouse hovering DataTable it imported package as import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;

```
@And("^verify for incorrect or incomplete Address$")
    public void verify_for_incorrect_or_incomplete_url(DataTable address) throws Throwable {
        List<List> data = address.
```

I am not sure what is missing in my dependency file, please guide.

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatable-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.12</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Your dependencies don't look right. You should only need `cucumber-java` and `cucumber-junit`. You should also look at the methods which the class provides. Your IDE should let you click through to data table class and its methods.

Answer (score 0):

the `raw()` method is outdated.

So you can instead do something like this:

```
List<List<String>> data = address.asLists(String.class);
```

The Result will be:

```
[[/api/], [/api/2020-05-30], [/api/20200404], [/api/abcfghj]]
```